# printing a value outside of the for loop

Tags: python

I am studying for a final in a beginners programming class. I received this question wrong on my midterm. I said the answer is 1, however, the answer is actually 0. I was wondering if anyone could explain to me why it is 0. Is it because z is originally assigned to 0? I am not sure how to tell if it's a local variable with this limited code. Thank you for any help you provide!

```
z=0
for x in range(1, 200, -1):
    z=z+1
print(z)
```

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with variable scope. Change the range into (1, 200, 1), observe the result and I think you will have an aha moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no elements at `range(1, 200, -1)`, the loop not even starts. So `z` never changed its value.

Read about the step(third arg of range) arg here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

A nice way to see this is convert the range to list:

```
print(list(range(1, 200, -1)))
>>> []
```

Answer (score 1):

You should test it out in your interpreter. The loop never makes an iteration. Think of what is being incremented.

Your range is 1 through 200, but you are choosing to increment by -1 at each step starting at 1, so you cannot move backwards in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It is staying zero because the range is 1, 200 but you are stepping by -1, so the expression inside the for loop is never actually executing.